# Correct usage of store.loadMany() function

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to figure out how to populate a table from a JSON object.
**My JSON is a structurated object:**

```
{ 
id: 0,
list: [{ username:'user_1',online:true, user:0 },
{ username:'user_2',online:true, user:0 }]
}
```

**My Model is defined as follow:**

```
MyTalk.WUser = DS.Model.extend({
list: DS.hasMany('MyTalk.User')
});

MyTalk.User = DS.Model.extend({
username: DS.attr('string'), // primary key
online: DS.attr('boolean'),
user: DS.belongsTo('MyTalk.WUser') 
});
```

**I am using a custom Adapter for ember-data:**

```
DS.SocketAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend(MyTalk.WebSocketConnection, {
// code not relevant
}

DS.SocketAdapter.map('MyTalk.WUser', {
list: {embedded: 'always'}
});

DS.SocketAdapter.map('MyTalk.User', {
primaryKey: 'username'
});
MyTalk.Store = DS.Store.extend({
revision: 12,
adapter: DS.SocketAdapter.create({})
});
```

Now I would load my data. I run in Chrome command line **the following statements**:

```
var store = DS.get('defaultStore');

var obj =  { 
id: 0,
list: [{ username:'user_1',online:true, user:0 },
{ username:'user_2',online:true, user:0 }]
};

var store.loadMany(MyTalk.WUser,obj);

var record = MyTalk.WUser.find(0);
record.serialize();
```

**But it returns no record:**

```
> Object {list: Array[0]}
```

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow the adapter to deserialize embedded records (or perform any custom deserialization, for that matter), you'll need to load your data through the adapter rather than directly into the store.

```
var store = DS.get('defaultStore'),
    obj = { 
      id: 0,
      list: [{ username:'user_1', online:true, user:0 },
             { username:'user_2', online:true, user:0 }]
    },
    type = MyTalk.WUser,
    adapter = store.adapterForType(type);

adapter.load(store, type, obj);
```

Comment: Is there a similar way to "loadMany"